# Angular directives not rendering as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am experimenting with directives in angular and I'm puzzled.

http://jsfiddle.net/S2cQD/2/

I have four directives: person, personWholeName, personFirstName, and personLastName. person calls the personWholeName directive. personWholeName calls the personFirstName and personLastName directives. But when I use the person directive, I don't see that the personLastName directive is rendered.

Here is my html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template"    id="partials/personFirstName.html">
    <span>{{first}}</span>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template"    id="partials/personLastName.html">
    <span>{{last}}</span>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/personWholeName.html">
    <div>
        <person-first-name first="name.first" />
        <person-last-name last="name.last" />
    </div>
</script>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/person.html">
    <div>
        <person-whole-name name="person.name" />
    </div>
</script>

<div ng-controller="MainAppController">
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="person.name.first" /><br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="person.name.last" /><br/>
    <person person="person" />
</div>
```

And then my script:

```
'use strict;'

var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['personModule'])
    .controller('MainAppController', function MainAppController($scope) {
        $scope.person = {
            name: {
                first: "John",
                last: "Smith"
            }
        };
    });

var personModule = angular.module('personModule', []);

personModule.directive('personFirstName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/personFirstName.html',
        scope: {
            first: '='
        }
    };
});

personModule.directive('personLastName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/personLastName.html',
        scope: {
            last: '='
        }
    };
});

personModule.directive('personWholeName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/personWholeName.html',
        scope: {
            name: '='
        }
    };
});

personModule.directive('person', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/person.html',
        scope: {
            person: '='
        }
    };
});
```

Any ideas about why the last name doesn't get rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're trying to get 2 directives in the same level to use a different scope.
Using, for example, a `span` to separate them fixes the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/S2cQD/6/

Comment: In newer versions of Angular an error should be logged if you try to create multiple scopes on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. Its working as is:

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vtU09RmH2bXmsDfMGG40?p=preview)

There is likely something wrong with jsFiddle.